# Definition of direct summand

Tags: modules

If M is an R-module ,and if N is a direct sum of M over an indexed set I, then is it correct to write:
N= T direct sum M, where T is the direct sum of M over I-{i} , where i in I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking if
$$\bigoplus_{j \in I} M = M \oplus \bigoplus_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} M.$$
The answer is yes.  But do you have some doubt about this that you want to clarify?